# Create Custom Json Error in Asp.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am using a JavaScript plug-in and if there is an error it expects format like;

```
{error: 'You are not allowed to upload such a file.'}
```

In my MVC Web API I am throwing error like;

```
 var error = string.Format("An error has been occured. Please try again later.");
                throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, error));
```

and it is represented in HTTP response like below;

```
{"Message":"An error has been occured. Please try again later."}
```

how can I achieve to return in first way?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an anonymous object

```
throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,new { error = "your error message here!"}));
```

Comment: This time it returns as {"error":"your error message here!"} with quotes. How can I eliminate that?

Comment: Why do you need it without the quotes ?

Comment: I think plug-in I am using is not accepting other than format {error: 'You are not allowed to upload such a file.'} Please see at http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo#async-send

Comment: You can parse the JSON String to an Javascript Object in order to use it like you need it. Example: JSON.parse("{\"error\":\"your error message here!\"}");